# radio button values send using ajax php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

Please help me with this.

It could be a duplicate question, but I couldn't find the solution anywhere.

I am creating an objective type questionnaire and the options are in radio buttons. Some of the options are mandatory and if the user click that option the comment box will change to a required field. The name of the answers are the question Id. Here is the input field which I am using

```
<input type='radio' name='answer_value[<?php echo $gques; ?>]' value='<?php echo $gans; ?>' id="rtr" onclick='ajaxFunction()'/>
```

I want to do it with ajax, because when the user select the mandatory option it has fetch the answer id and use that id to execute a query to check whether that answer is mandatory or not. If true it will make the comment box a required text area. The ajax code I used is

```
function ajaxFunction(){    
   var ajaxRequest;    
       try{    
           ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();    
       }catch (e){    
       try{    
           ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");    
       }catch (e) {    
       try{    
           ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");    
       }catch (e){    
           alert("Your browser broke!");    
       return false;    
             }    
          }    
       }    
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){    
if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){    
   var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');    
   ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;    
      }    
   }    

var ans_id = $("input[id=rtr]:checked").val();    
        var dataString = 'id='+ ans_id;    
        alert(dataString);    

        ajaxRequest.open("POST", "anschq.php" +dataString,true);    
        ajaxRequest.send();    
    }
```

In the anschq.php I put an alert script to check whether the value is sent or not. But when I click on the radio button the alert box is not displayed from the other page. 
But the alert(dataString) here is displaying the value of the checked button.

Can anyone find the solution for this problem.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a GET request. You have to pass the data in the body of the response not in the url (see [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)).

Replace:

```
ajaxRequest.open("POST", "anschq.php" + dataString, true);    
ajaxRequest.send();
```

by

```
ajaxRequest.open("POST", "anschq.php", true);    
ajaxRequest.send(dataString);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed it according to your answer but it did not made any difference. How do I check whether the POST value is send or not without executing the next page, ie., ansshq.php ?

Comment: In Chrome, you can open the debug mode (right click, examinate element, Network section) and check XHR, you should see in the detail of your request what is sent. Tell me if I'm not clear. Can you show me an example of the format of your dataString? If you didn't do it, try to remove the `?` at the beginning of dataString.

Comment: Yes I did that and when I click any of the button, 404 error shown in the Network section. I changed the code to,    $(document).ready(function () {        $('input:radio').click(function(){
            var ans_id = $("input[id=rtr]:checked").val();
            var dataString = 'id='+ ans_id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: dataString,
            url: "anschq.php",
            success : function( data ){
                alert(dataString);
            }
        });
        });
    }); 
And for this code no error is thrown and the output is same

Comment: Does the alert(dataString) is processed here?

Comment: Yes, this code also shows the alert message. But there are no error in the network session. The format of the dataString which I am sending are just integers

Comment: Could you add the part of `anschq.php` where you don't have what you want?

Comment: The content of the anschq.php you mean. It is nothing but some scripts to execute, like 'alert' to check whether the arguments are passed to that page. If the arguments are passed to that page the scripts must execute right? Note : echo-ing the post value also not working in that page

Comment: `anschq.php` is a PHP file and `alert` is not a PHP function. Maybe all what you want is use `echo` instead? You can show me your PHP code if you want.

Comment: <?php

echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("s");</script>';
exit;
exit;
?>

This is the code which I used and I did put an exit because I believe that clicking a radio button will return a blank page

Comment: You have to add the result of your AJAX request to the DOM for it to be interpreted. Use this success method in your JQuery AJAX request: `success: function(data) { $('body').append(data); }`

Comment: It Worked :D ... Thank you very much @Gnucki. If I had know that particular success method I shouldn't have wasted half of my day. Thanks again...

Comment: Glad I could help you. If you want to be helped in your PHP developement I would suggest you the framework [Symfony2](http://symfony.com/). It will help you for security, forms, manipulating your data (using a database) and many other important things essential to a professional website.

Comment: Ofcourse I will have a look at it. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: You should certainly mark the question as answered if it's ok for you. Of course, if you want more advices, you can let it opened.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for the option to rate your comment which solved  my issue. Sadly I don't have enough reputations to rate I believe. Anyway I will mark the answer which you gave first as the correct one.

Comment: Yes, you need at least 15 rep. I rated your question to give you a little more reputation.